# Floating fixed position cart

Tags: addtocart, mini-cart

I need to add floating cart with product count in my site(screenshot_1). Which is now in header minicart. I need to fix minicart in right side of my site.

How I can do that?

screenshot_1
[image]

Comment: Can you show your header here

Comment: @VigneshBala Did not understood that you asking or suggesting. I need only cart here not full header.

Comment: Take screenshot for your header and display as image here, Currently the minicart  is displayed or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.minicart-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 20%; /* adjust as needed */
    .block-minicart { right : 10px; } 
    /* so the content window doesn't overflow over the right side of the page */
}
```

You can do this using just a couple of lines of CSS.

Comment: Ohh Dear. Sorry for late response. I have solved this issue. Thanks a lot :)